# Redirect after end void method

Tags: angular, redirect, navigation, components, subscribe

I have a problem while refreshing my page

I have a service that runs the following code:

**service.ts**

```
public goToCommit(value: boolean) {
    if (this.accountServ.isAutho() || this.person.getNb() % 48 === 0) {
        this.personService.savePerson(this.person).subscribe(() => {
          this.person= null;
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Account not authorized to goToCommit');
      }
  }
```

(this treatment is long, 
this method is used in other places
)

in my component I have this:

**component.ts**

```
this.service.goToCommit(value);
this.router.navigate (['/persons']);
```

The problem is that I am redirected to `/persons` before the processing ends.

How can I wait for the `goToCommit` method to finish and redirect after ?

Thank you

Comment: `How can I wait for the goToCommit method to finish and redirect after ?` ← Return an observable from the method and subscribe to it in your component. In your service method you can use `tab` (`.pipe(tap(() => this.person = null))` to still set the value of `this.person`.

Comment: return new Observable<void>();    like this ?

Comment: No, return the observable. `if(conditionHere) { return this.personService.savePerson(this.person).pipe(tap(() => this.person = null)); } else { throw new....};`

Comment: this error is generated
`Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)
`

Comment: So the service returns the observable, the component subscribes to that observable. `this.service.goToCommit(value).subscribe(() => this.router.navigate (['/persons']););`

Comment: i can't subscribe in the component .. just unsubscribe..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213098/discussion-between-nitneuq-and-igor).